# How to join summary statistics as new variables for each statistics back to original dataframe

Tags: r, join, dplyr, data-manipulation, summary

need help to create a function so that this function can produce summary statistics joined back to the original but named after the column (with a prefix (i.e. cyl_event_pct, cyl_distn_events for each variable with values to the corresponding variable in the data frame. The function will require input parameters both the dataframe, and the independent variable. in the example below, the independent variable will be mtcars$am

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl,gear,vs,am) 

df %>%
  gather(variable,value, -ncol(df)) %>%
  group_by(variable, value) %>%
  summarise (n = n(),
             n_events = sum(am),
             event_pct = round(mean(am),4)
  ) %>%
  mutate(distn_events = round(n_events/sum(n_events),4))
```

Would like to add event_pct and distn_events as new variable to original df.

```
   # A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   variable [3]
  variable value     n n_events event_pct distn_events
     <chr> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1      cyl     4    11        8    0.7273       0.6154
2      cyl     6     7        3    0.4286       0.2308
3      cyl     8    14        2    0.1429       0.1538
4     gear     3    15        0    0.0000       0.0000
5     gear     4    12        8    0.6667       0.6154
6     gear     5     5        5    1.0000       0.3846
7       vs     0    18        6    0.3333       0.4615
8       vs     1    14        7    0.5000       0.5385
```

hope to see a dataframe after with additional columns added as cyl_event_pct, cyl_distn_events, gear_event_pct, gear_distn_events to the below table with values to the corresponding variable in the data frame(excluding the independent variable of am)

```
df
                    cyl gear vs am
Mazda RX4             6    4  0  1
Mazda RX4 Wag         6    4  0  1
Datsun 710            4    4  1  1
Hornet 4 Drive        6    3  1  0
Hornet Sportabout     8    3  0  0
Valiant               6    3  1  0
Duster 360            8    3  0  0
Merc 240D             4    4  1  0
Merc 230              4    4  1  0
Merc 280              6    4  1  0
Merc 280C             6    4  1  0
```

Thank you in advanced you masters of the universe!
JT

Comment: What's `char_col`?

Comment: i've corrected it. char_col was meant to be names(df) without the independent variable. -ncol() will now remove the last variable which is the independent variable am

Comment: So to be clear, the Datsun 710 has cyl=6 so you want to pick up the row with variable="cyl" value=6 and give the Datsun 710 row a value of 0.4286 to a column called cyl_event_pct?

Comment: spot on. the car doesn't really matter at all. i was getting statistics for cyl for each numeric, gear for each numeric, vs for each numeric types...so on and so forth. in your example, the merc 280c will have the same statistics as the mazda rx4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
cols <- c("cyl", "gear", "vs")
df[paste0(cols,"_event_pct")] <- lapply(cols, function(x) df_stat[df_stat$variable==x,"event_pct"][match(df[[x]], df_stat[df_stat$variable==x,"value"])])
df[paste0(cols,"_distn_events")] <- lapply(cols, function(x) df_stat[df_stat$variable==x,"distn_events"][match(df[[x]], df_stat[df_stat$variable==x,"value"])])
df
```

Output is:

```
                  cyl gear vs am cyl_event_pct gear_event_pct vs_event_pct cyl_distn_events gear_distn_events vs_distn_events
Mazda RX4           6    4  0  1        0.4286         0.6667       0.3333           0.2308            0.6154          0.4615
Mazda RX4 Wag       6    4  0  1        0.4286         0.6667       0.3333           0.2308            0.6154          0.4615
Datsun 710          4    4  1  1        0.7273         0.6667       0.5000           0.6154            0.6154          0.5385
Hornet 4 Drive      6    3  1  0        0.4286         0.0000       0.5000           0.2308            0.0000          0.5385
Hornet Sportabout   8    3  0  0        0.1429         0.0000       0.3333           0.1538            0.0000          0.4615
Valiant             6    3  1  0        0.4286         0.0000       0.5000           0.2308            0.0000          0.5385
Duster 360          8    3  0  0        0.1429         0.0000       0.3333           0.1538            0.0000          0.4615
Merc 240D           4    4  1  0        0.7273         0.6667       0.5000           0.6154            0.6154          0.5385
Merc 230            4    4  1  0        0.7273         0.6667       0.5000           0.6154            0.6154          0.5385
Merc 280            6    4  1  0        0.4286         0.6667       0.5000           0.2308            0.6154          0.5385
Merc 280C           6    4  1  0        0.4286         0.6667       0.5000           0.2308            0.6154          0.5385
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(cyl = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L), gear = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), vs = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), am = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("cyl", "gear", "vs", 
"am"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", 
"Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C"
))
> dput(df_stat)
structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("cyl", "gear", "vs"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L), n = c(11L, 7L, 
    14L, 15L, 12L, 5L, 18L, 14L), n_events = c(8L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
    8L, 5L, 6L, 7L), event_pct = c(0.7273, 0.4286, 0.1429, 0, 
    0.6667, 1, 0.3333, 0.5), distn_events = c(0.6154, 0.2308, 
    0.1538, 0, 0.6154, 0.3846, 0.4615, 0.5385)), .Names = c("variable", 
"value", "n", "n_events", "event_pct", "distn_events"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: That's awesome. You did it! i've posted a function based on your input. below.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt to writing a function using Prem's solution. If there is a more elegant way of doing this, please let me know.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cols <- c("cyl", "gear", "vs")
y <- 'am'

gen_stat_df <- function(df, char_col, y){

  my_df <- df %>%  
    select(char_col,y)

  excl_y_cols <- setdiff(char_col,y)

  #create summary statistics
  df_stat <- my_df %>%
    gather(variable,value, excl_y_cols) %>%
    group_by(variable, value) %>%
    summarise (n = n(),
               n_events = sum(!! rlang::sym(y)),
               event_pct = round(mean(!! rlang::sym(y)),4)
    ) %>%
    mutate(distn_events = round(n_events/sum(n_events),4)) %>% data.frame()

  df[paste0(char_col,"_distn_events")] <- lapply(char_col, function(x) df_stat[df_stat$variable==x,"distn_events"][match(df[[x]], df_stat[df_stat$variable==x,"value"])])

  return(df)

}
gen_stat_df(mtcars,cols,y)
```

and the output

```
> gen_stat_df(mtcars,cols,y)
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl_distn_events gear_distn_events
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4           0.2308            0.6154
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4           0.2308            0.6154
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1           0.6154            0.6154
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1           0.2308            0.0000
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2           0.1538            0.0000
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1           0.2308            0.0000
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4           0.1538            0.0000
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2           0.6154            0.6154
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2           0.6154            0.6154
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4           0.2308            0.6154
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4           0.2308            0.6154
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3           0.1538            0.0000
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3           0.1538            0.0000
```